# Run blank typescript project

Tags: node.js, html, typescript, npm

I would like to run a blank typescript project with a package.json, typescript and html file.- Similar to the Stackblitz blank-typescript [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qj6tc3).
Can anyone maybe provide me a step by step guidance, how to setup such a project. Im currently using Webstorm as an IDE if this is important to know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I have my solution.

#### Step 1

install typescript on your project with `npm install typescript --save`

#### Step2

create a tsconfig file to apply typescript rules for your project with `tsc --init`

#### Step 3

create a index.ts and index.html file
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Promises vs. Observables</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.ts:

```
const world = '️';

const appDiv: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('app');

if (appDiv) {
    appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello ${world}</h1>`;
    console.log(`hello ${world}`);
}
```

### Last step

Compile in watch mode with `tsc -w`

Project is running! If I can do something better on my solution, dont hesitate to tell me!

Comment: Small note: you don't need a union type of `null` added to your `appDiv` declaration. Most _types_ (`HTMLElement` included) can contain the _value_ `null` already. Prove this to yourself by compiling `const appDiv: HTMLElement = null;`. What that union declaration means is that `appDiv` can contain the _type_ `<HTMLElement>` or the _type_ `<null>`, which is not exactly what you want. While the difference is arguably just semantic, typescript is about semantics.

Comment: I did that because my tsconfig file was set with `strict: true`. After turning it into false, I didnt need to add null as a type.

Comment: @Fantasia / all - the stackblitz example does not import index.js in index.html. Do you know how it works without the import? I understand there might be a "DEV" reload server running which might be transpiling .ts file to .js files but how is the file being imported? https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-msdeuu?file=index.html

Comment: anyone have webpack config for this?